# Send private message using Node.js and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

I am implementing a small chat application using node.js and socket.io. Everything goes well till I try to send a private message. Here is the code for the server:

```
...
var to = users[name];
socket.to(to).emit('private message', {userName: socket.username, message: msg} );
...
```

Code on the client side:

```
...
socket.on('private message', function(data){
    alert(data.message);
});
...
```

My problem is that on the client side the event is never fired, can anyone help me to fix this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is too late to answer..

You can use `socket.id` to send private message or send data privately.

```
io.on('connect', function(){
    io.to(socket.id).emit('send message', 'test');
});
```